# Soma foreach dentro de foreach

Tags: php

Estou com uma dúvida sobre o por quê a soma dentro do foreach não está funcionando.

Resolvi a situação de outro modo, recriando um novo select com count(*).

Porém gostaria de saber se estou fazendo algo errado, ou se dá pra fazer isso de outra forma utilizando essa mesma estrutura.

A situação é esta:

O foreach principal busca todos entregadores que existem na tabela pedido.

O segundo foreach traz somente as formas de pagamento onde determinados entregadores estejam associados .

Gostaria de saber o porque código abaixo não esta funcionando, uma vez que, ao realizar um var_dump($TOTQtdeFormaRetorno) ao invés de exibir o TOTAL 15 , ele exibe os valores conteúdo que preciso somar .

```
foreach($EntregasResumo_rs = $sqlEntregas_res->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $Entregas_rs){
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td width='3px' >".$Entregas_rs['IdEntregador'  ]."</td>";
            echo "<td             >".$Entregas_rs['NomeEntregador']."</td>";
            echo "<td class='vlrc'>".$Entregas_rs['QtdeEntrega'   ]."</td>";
             // Variável $IdEntregadorResumo pra usar no select;
                $IdEntregadorResumo = $Entregas_rs['IdEntregador' ]; 

            echo "<td class='vlrc'>";
                    $sql_EntregasRetorno="select ped.identregador as IdEntregador, count(*) as QtdeFormaRetorno, fpgto.Descricao from pedidoformapgto pedf  
                    inner join pedido ped on pedf.codpedido = ped.codpedido  inner join cdformapgto fpgto on pedf.codforma = fpgto.codforma     
                    where ped.dtmovto = '$DtMov' and ped.status  = 'BT'  and ped.codtpentr = 1  and ped.identregador <> 0 and
                    fpgto.descricao in('RETORNO') and ped.identregador = '$IdEntregadorResumo'
                    group by ped.identregador, fpgto.descricao  order by ped.identregador";

                    $sql_EntregasRetorno = $conn->prepare($sql_EntregasRetorno);
                    $sql_EntregasRetorno->execute();    
                    $rs_EntregasRetorno = $sql_EntregasRetorno->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);                 

                    foreach($rs_EntregasRetorno as $rr_EntregasRetorno)
                        {
                            echo $QtdeRetorno = $rr_EntregasRetorno['QtdeFormaRetorno'];

                            $TOTQtdeFormaRetorno = 0;   
                            $TOTQtdeFormaRetorno += $rr_EntregasRetorno['QtdeFormaRetorno']; 

            echo "</td>";
                        var_dump($TOTQtdeFormaRetorno); 
                        } //Segundo foreach;
```

Este foreach recebe o $IdEntregadorResumo para poder exibir os entregadores que estão associados à uma determinada Forma de Pagamento

Segue abaixo o resultado do var_dump($TOTQtdeFormaRetorno);

```
C:\wamp64\www\solus\resumo_dia.php:384:int 4
C:\wamp64\www\solus\resumo_dia.php:384:int 1
C:\wamp64\www\solus\resumo_dia.php:384:int 3
C:\wamp64\www\solus\resumo_dia.php:384:int 2
C:\wamp64\www\solus\resumo_dia.php:384:int 2
C:\wamp64\www\solus\resumo_dia.php:384:int 1
C:\wamp64\www\solus\resumo_dia.php:384:int 1
C:\wamp64\www\solus\resumo_dia.php:384:int 1
//O resultado que eu esperava do var_dump era 15
```

> Abaixo tenho este código que fiz e esta funcionando. A diferença entre eles é que o código abaixo não está dentro de um foreach.

Tenho um código que esta funcionando perfeitamente, que é este:
Ele pega o resultado de cada linha e esta armazenando em cada variável que , exibo no final, esse código não esta dentro de laço.

```
$sql_EntregasTot= $conn->prepare($sql_EntregasTot);
    $sql_EntregasTot->execute();
    $TOTQtdeEntregas     = 0;
    $TOTVlrTaxas         = 0;
    $TOTQtdeEntregadores = 0;

    $TOTEntregas       = $sql_EntregasTot->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    foreach($TOTEntregas as $TOTEntregas_Resumo)
        {
            $TOTQtdeEntregas     += $TOTEntregas_Resumo['QtdeEntrega'] ;
            $TOTVlrTaxas         += $TOTEntregas_Resumo['VlrTaxa']     ;
            $TOTQtdeEntregadores += 1                                  ;
        }
```

[image: Tela]

Comment: Antes do primeiro foreach, crie uma variável que será o total geral: `$somatotal = 0;`... e após o segundo foreach, você soma com o valor do segundo foreach: `$somatotal += $TOTQtdeFormaRetorno;`

Comment: Seria algo assim: https://jsfiddle.net/rb95d8pz/

Comment: Tenta implementar array_sum($TOTQtdeFormaRetorno); Essa função soma todos o valores dentro de uma array.

Comment: Quando tento usar o array_sum ele apresenta o seguinte erro:

"Warning: array_sum() expects parameter 1 to be array, integer given in C:\wamp64\www\solus\resumo_dia.php on line 390"

Estou fazendo assim: 
$SOMA = array_sum($TOTQtdeFormaRetorno); 
var_dump($SOMA);

Comment: @dvd :  Com esse parâmetro que vocÇe me passou ele soma linha a linha até chegar no resultado final, note que o valor final é 15 o que é o esperado.
C:\wamp64\www\solus\resumo_dia.php:391:int 4
C:\wamp64\www\solus\resumo_dia.php:391:int 5
C:\wamp64\www\solus\resumo_dia.php:391:int 8
C:\wamp64\www\solus\resumo_dia.php:391:int 10
C:\wamp64\www\solus\resumo_dia.php:391:int 12
C:\wamp64\www\solus\resumo_dia.php:391:int 13
C:\wamp64\www\solus\resumo_dia.php:391:int 14
C:\wamp64\www\solus\resumo_dia.php:391:int 15

Comment: Então... vc pode pegar esse valor e jogar na coluna da linha final da tabela.

Answer (score 0):

Eu não entendi bem, mas não seria o caso da tua variavel estar setando a todo momento o valor zero em:

```
$TOTQtdeFormaRetorno = 0;
```

Deveria estar fora do segundo foreach, não? Assim:

```
$TOTQtdeFormaRetorno = 0;

foreach($rs_EntregasRetorno as $rr_EntregasRetorno)
{
    echo $QtdeRetorno = $rr_EntregasRetorno['QtdeFormaRetorno'];

    $TOTQtdeFormaRetorno += $rr_EntregasRetorno['QtdeFormaRetorno']; 

    echo "</td>";
    var_dump($TOTQtdeFormaRetorno); 
}
```

Comment: Quando coloco fora ele se comporta da mesma forma.

Comment: @JeffersonAmorim vc quer somar todos valores retornados de `$rs_EntregasRetorno` a cada loop, não é isso?

Comment: Isso mesmo , seria uma soma simples mesmo, mas que aqui não esta funcionando.
Registro1:  1
Registro2:  5
Registro3:  2

Soma:        8

Comment: Eu já fiz esse processo, algumas vezes e todos funcionaram, com um simples while/for,  assim como com foreach.  A unica diferença é que nenhuma das outras vezes era um laço dentro de outro laço.

Answer (score 0):

Problema resolvido.

Inicializei as variáveis antes da linha do *foreach principal*  (pois como informei dentro desse foreach tinha outros foreach dependem do resultado desse primeiro).

```
    $TOTQtdeRetornos     = 0;                                          
    $TOTQtdeBonificacao  = 0; 
    foreach($EntregasResumo_rs = $sqlEntregas_res->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $Entregas_rs)
    {
```

E no final desse foreach principal fiz a soma.

```
    $TOTQtdeRetornos    += $QtdeRetorno;
    $TOTQtdeBonificacao += $QtdeBonificacao;
}
```

Agradeço a todos que me auxiliaram e me ajudaram chegar nessa solução.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]